# SQL with max(date) to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

I have tried to make the following sql in linq with no luck can some help mw with this?

```
select * from customer c
where companynumber = 1 
      and status <> 0 
      and lastdate = (select max(lastdate) from customer where customernumber = c.customernumber)
```

Gives 22 records

My best try was this:

```
_ctx.Customers
    .Where(r => r.CompanyNumber == companyNumber && r.CustomerNumber != null && r.Status != 0)
    .GroupBy(c => c.CustomerNumber)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        name = g.Key,
        count = g.Count(),
        date = g.Max(x => x.LastEdited)
    })
    .OrderBy(c => c.name);
```

Gives 22.000+ records

But not the result as the above SQL

UPDATE:

The following LINQ does the trick ;o)

```
from a in _ctx.Customers
where a.CustomerNumber != null && a.CompanyNumber == companyNumber
group a by new { a.CustomerNumber } into g
select g.OrderByDescending(a => a.LastEdited).FirstOrDefault() into c
where c.Status == 1
select c
```

I had to move the `where c.Status == 1` into my first select statment

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Every time a customer is updated a new record is created with a new date and status set to 0. I want to get all customers where the latest record has status 1